# `GCC 4.9.2` не поддерживает манипулятор `std::defaultfloat`?

Tags: c++, c++11

`GCC 4.9.2` не поддерживает манипулятор `std::defaultfloat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, используйте GCC 5+. Там он [поддерживается](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html).